# VS 2017 Release Management Tokenize XPath/Regular expressions not working

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to use the Release Management Tokenize XPath/Regular and I keep getting different error as I try to answer the three entries

1. **Source filename:** $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/XXXXX/Drop - This I know is on my build server  this file should be
   xxxxxx.exe.config and is located in a zip file
2. **Destination filename:** I don't know if this should be on the build server or the release server?
3. **Configuration Json filename:** I don't really know where to put this, the code below is the Json file.

   {
       "DEV": {

   ```
       "ConfigChanges": [{
           "KeyName": "/configuration/loggingConfiguration/listeners/add[@name='Email Trace Listener']",
           "Attribute": "emailListId",
           "value": 0
       },
       {
           "KeyName": "/configuration/loggingConfiguration/listeners/add[@name='Email Trace Listener']",
           "Attribute": "subjectLineStarter",
           "value": "[DEV]: Program Name"
       },
       {
           "KeyName": "/configuration/loggingConfiguration/listeners/add[@name='Email Trace Listener']",
           "Attribute": "smtpServer",
           "value": "testsmtp.dns.com"
       },
       {
           "KeyName": "/configuration/loggingConfiguration/listeners/add[@name='Email Trace Listener']",
           "Attribute": "toAddress",
           "value": "application.support.test@Yahoo.com"
       }]
   }
   ```

   }

**My Error**

```
2019-04-01T16:40:08.4509133Z ##[section]Starting: Tokenizer: Transform Source filename
2019-04-01T16:40:08.4663688Z ==============================================================================
2019-04-01T16:40:08.4663688Z Task         : Tokenize with XPath/Regular expressions
2019-04-01T16:40:08.4663688Z Description  : Replaces __<variable>__ and/or XPath for XML documents with User Defined variables or configuration json document
2019-04-01T16:40:08.4663688Z Version      : 2.1.0
2019-04-01T16:40:08.4663688Z Author       : ms-devlabs
2019-04-01T16:40:08.4663688Z Help         : [More Information](https://github.com/openalm/Extension-UtilitiesPack)
2019-04-01T16:40:08.4663688Z ==============================================================================
2019-04-01T16:40:10.6850718Z Environment: DEV
2019-04-01T16:40:10.8413250Z Updating emailListId of /configuration/loggingConfiguration/listeners/add[@name='Email Trace Listener']: 0
2019-04-01T16:40:10.9350669Z ##[error]Failure while updating emailListId of /configuration/loggingConfiguration/listeners/add[@name='Email Trace Listener']: 0
2019-04-01T16:40:10.9663179Z ##[section]Finishing: Tokenizer: Transform Source filename
```

in My .proj file I put this so that I could get the App.Config.Token file on release instead of App.Config.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
    <None Include="App.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="App.config.Token">
      <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

The App.config  and App.Debug.config are identical.
The App.Config.Token

Comment: The task you're showing an error message for has nothing to do with tokenization.

Comment: Well the error may be incorrect, but the it is the process I am trying to create.  I have the Auto.config and I created an Auto.Config.Token  in the same directory.  When I perform the build task I need the Auto.Config.Token to be picked up, so that the program.exe.config will have the items to be replaced.

Comment: Your question is saying you're attempting to do one thing. The error message you're seeing is for a **totally different thing** that is not related to your question. No one can help with the question without more details on what isn't working **with the subject of the question**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the tokenization process we are currently using (we don't zip the build results, see suggestions for extensions below):

BUILD:

Replace App.Config with App.Config.Token with, for example, copy command in command line -task.

RELEASE

For each environment/stage:

- Use "Replace Tokens" -extension for .config. This reads the environment-specific variables from release definition and replaces the tokens in .config (which was replaced by .config.token in the build)
- Do the deployment

Replacing tokens inside an archive needs a different extension, [Tokenize in archive](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=solidify-labs.vsts-task-tokenize-in-archive) might be an option there. We use [Colin's Build and Release tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=colinsalmcorner.colinsalmcorner-buildtasks), which has nifty tokenizator for json-files. I prefer Colin's tokenizer, as it's pretty straightforward and one doesn't have to dabble with XPATH and transformations. We also use [Json to Variables](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OneLuckiDev.json2variable) for storing environment variables in VC, instead of storing them in release definitions. I suspect the last one won't work in TFS 2017, but haven't tried.

As for the original question, I suspect that the extension you are using can't read the file you're trying to tokenize from inside the archive. Haven't used that extension myself, but i'd put the JSON-file to version control so it ends up in the build artifact. The destination filename implies that the extension could write out the final config-file, likely replacing the original app.config.